# How to deal with a micromanaging manager?

Tags: management

My manager told me to not say:

> I might be wrong so maybe it can take a little more time, but I doubt
> it.

and to instead say:

> I might be wrong so maybe it can take a little more time, let me know
> if that’s the case.

Because it sounded too rude to him. I am not sure if this is a normal feedback. What do you do if he keeps giving useless feedbacks like these? I would understand if it sounded rude, but this doesn't sound rude at all.

Comment: Sorry, but rating the politeness of a statement would be a matter of personal opinion.

Comment: What's the context here - are you directing that statement at someone or is it a response to a question you've been asked?

Comment: Has this happened before with other things or is it the first time? If it's the first time, just put it down as a quirk and move on.

Comment: Weird. I will assume English is his first language, and he’s not very good at it. What you said is perfectly fine.

Comment: This is not micromanagement. Nor is it useless. He is giving you advice/instructions about your interactions with other team members.

Comment: So is it perfectly fine or not? Because there's no way this sounds arrogant or rude.

Comment: What is the most important thing here? That the task is completed, or that you know when it will be completed so you can plan further tasks. 
When given first statement, if the task took longer I would *actively avoid* telling you. You won't have an idea how much progress has been made, or when to expect it to be complete.
When given the second statement you invite a conversation. If the task is not complete on time, I will get in contact with you. I will let you know the difficulties I've had in case you can help, and we can try and re-estimate when it should be finished so you can plan.

Comment: In a situation where It's 100% certain and almost anyone would have said that?

Comment: @kingsready - people here *are* disagreeing with you. Maybe you can add some more context into the question (or ask a new one) to change the situation, but right now it seems like you are only looking for agreement and not to be challenged.

Answer (score 4):

**This is not micromanagement. Nor is it useless.**

He is advising you that something you say is coming over badly, possibly as arrogant. It may be just him that finds it like that, but he may also be passing on complaints from your co-workers (done in such a way that he doesn't let you know which of your co-workers have complained). And it's not useless, because if your co-workers think you are rude or arrogant then that's a problem for you. It doesn't matter if you think it's rude or not.

It's also unlikely that he is saying this based just on one thing you said. It may be about a general perception of how you interact with people.

Take his advice seriously. Depending on culture you may be doing something quite rude.

Comment: There's no way this can be construed as rude under any culture. Am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, you are. " I doubt it." implies a disbelief that you might make a mistake.

Comment: It feels a little rude to me (British). It's very abrupt, and by 'doubting' that it will take longer you are calling into question the integrity of anyone from whom it does take longer - implying they are lazy, are not as smart as you, or are trying to deceive you.

Comment: Well, it was in response to the guy who I was replying to saying it shouldn't be too hard. So I don't think it's rude at all.

Comment: I'm sure you think that. But the point of my answer is that even if you think it's not rude, other people might. And that's a problem.

Comment: @kingsready - I find the first version of the statement, the one your supervisor wants you to change, as offsetting personally myself. You might want to listen to your supervisor on this one. Of course I am the type of person, that would respond to such a statement with a very simple response, "prove it".